Stuck with with Regex/C#
i'm stuck sorting this out and thought it could be a good use for Regex (i seldom use it)
I need to extract elements from within a string (Code 128 barcode) that takes this form, usually:
(01)98723498723409(10)DF1234
(01) and (10) are different elements from within the barcode value, and i'm trying to get what is AFTER (01) (up until the next element), so, it would be 98723498723409
Also, if i wanted to get the (10) element, it would be just DF1234
I wanted to do it regardless of the position, sometimes there would be other elements/tags involved apart from (01) and (10)
Thanks in advance

Splitting with ) (and then trimming ( in the resulted items) would give you odd/even elements that you could use as "key-values". If you have a regex issue, show the regex and how you use it.

Using Regex.Split(..)  in the style string[] result = Regex.Split("(\\(\\d+\\))"); will give the numbers in brackets and the other text in alternating elements. The regex is (\(\d+\)) but the backslashes need escaping in the C# string.

You could just use IndexOf and Substring and not bother with a Regex

Multiple examples would clarify this greatly.
